# Swift - How do you smoothly hide/show the status bar between multiple view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

For example, on my current VC, I am not showing the status bar but when I modally present another VC that shows the status bar, the current one does a shift animation which looks choppy. How could I go about not messing with the current VC and having the modally presented one fade in the status bar as it slides up?

Comment: use   override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Answer (score 2):

```
  var hideStatusBar = false

  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { 
    return .slide
  }

  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { 
    return hideStatusBar 
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    hideStatusBar = true
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
  }
```

This code will slide the the status bar up smoothly once your view appears.  You can also try a different animation by replacing:

```
  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { 
    return .slide
  }
```

with:

```
  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation { 
    return .fade
  }
```

Comment: This does not seem to have any effect. Statusbar still simply appears.

Comment: I just edited my answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: replace this line --> setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() with the following UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() }

Answer (score 2):

Add a flag that determines if status bar is hidden

```
var statusBarHidden = false
```

Override `prefersStatusBarHidden`

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return statusBarHidden
}
```

Add utility function to update status bar visibility with animation

```
func setStatusBar(hidden: Bool) {
    statusBarHidden = hidden
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }) { (success: Bool) in
        print("status bar animated to hidden: \(statusBarHidden)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use self.prefersStatusBarHidden() depending on Particular View

```
 override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I have that, it works fine except that on the VC I'm presenting modally, I have it set to false so as It's loading, it shifts the one I was in down which creates a bad effect imo. Is there a way to delay the presentation of the status bar?

Comment: Write  prefersStatusBarHidden as false/true in ShareViewController VC

Comment: This will not animate but rather bring in or out the status bar abruptly.

Comment: ^Exactly. It does not produce a smooth transition